# Check user in put and display a massage whether it is right or wrong using java Script

Tags: javascript, textbox, user-input, message, display

i tried various ways to accomplish my codes with  out a success due to some reason. please if any one can help me for complete this task. my object is to check the in put from user and display a massage via a label near the text box mentioning the answer whether it is right or wrong in my website. i tried the following codes with out a success

i have in included screen shot of html and the java script codes

```
function but001() {
    var text001;
      var anws001 = pin1.value;
      if (anws001 == 1) {
      text001 = "answer is correct";
      }
      else {
      text001 = "answer is incorrect"; 
        document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML="text001";
      }
    }
```

Comment: [This jsfiddle](https://kooi.dev/showFiddle/k8nLrsve) may help?

Answer (score 0):

Try
`document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = text001;` (without the double quotes around `text001`)

Comment: i tried the suggestion but still dosn't show any interaction with the label, when i enter a number and click the button (it suppose to show "answer is correct" or "wrong"

Comment: is there any way that i can get check my html code to see is there anything wrong please some one advice me how i can upload my codes to view in this thread.